# How do I add Gluon Charm Library to my project in VScode

Tags: javafx, gluonfx

I'm working on a project that uses Swing but decided I'd add an FXML file that'll show up when user clicks on certain button. I'm getting getting issue

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ToggleButtonGroup
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:3062)
        at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:3051)
        at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2992)
        ... 33 more
```

The FXML file contains a ToggleButtonGroup element. The project isnt set up as a Java Project in VScode so i'm not sure if this is something I can just add to VMArgs in launch.json

I have already downloaded Gluon Charm jar file.

Comment: Use `JFXPanel`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+JFXPanel), "a component to embed JavaFX content into Swing applications." To examine the problem in isolation, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.